# How to detect app launched first time in a day

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have app, whenever it launched first time in day then I should execute some logic. I have checked in google but I didnt get any good working logic,
If anybody knows this, pls suggest me.

till now I have tried with this code

```
       var firstTime = new Date().getTime();
       if(window.localStorage.getItem('firstTime') == null){
            window.localStorage.setItem('firstTime', firstTime);
        }else{
            var secondTime = new Date().getTime();
            var storedTime = window.localStorage.getItem('firstTime');
            if(secondTime > storedTime){
                alert("Second time");
            }else{
                alert("First time");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use **SharedPReference** to check if the app opens first time in day.

Comment: @Clairvoyant  I am using Javascript in phonegap.. Same in localstorage also i can save data like sharedpreference. But how do we check app is opens first time in day..

Comment: You need to store the `date` part of it and check whether the current `date` is greater or not. Your logic will always say **Second time** because you are comparing **time** and not **date**

Comment: SharedPreference should help you in this matter.

Comment: @camelCaseCoder Sounds good, can u pls give me example with code

Comment: Instead of `new Date().getTime()`, consider `Date.now()`.

Comment: @RobG Date has no method like now()

Comment: @MallikarjunHampannavar please check my answer

Comment: @MallikarjunHampannavar—[*really*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.now)? It's been part of ECMA-262 since the beginning.

Comment: I agree with Clairvoyant, just using shared preference to store the date is more then enough to know if its opened today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in:

```
var firstTime = new Date().getTime();
if(window.localStorage.getItem('firstTime') == null){
    window.localStorage.setItem('firstTime', firstTime);
```

you are storing a number that represents the current moment to the millisecond. If you want the start of the day, set the hours to zero first:

```
var firstTime = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

Now do the logic, storing the time value is fine:

```
if (window.localStorage.getItem('firstTime') == null){
    window.localStorage.setItem('firstTime', firstTime);
```

In the else part, you need to compare to another time value for the start of the day, just like above:

```
} else {

  var storedTime = window.localStorage.getItem('firstTime');

  // Get a new date, zero it as above and see if its the same time
  // If not, it must be a different day
  var secondTime = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)

  if (secondTime != +firstTime) {
    alert("Second time is a different day");

  } else {
    alert("First time is the same day");
  }
}
```

Comment: if (secondTime != +firstTime) {
    alert("Second time is a different day");

  } else {
    alert("First time is the same day");
  }  is this work?? Second time is a different day is the first time of the same day right??

Comment: @MallikarjunHampannavar I don't understand where the confusion is, the `setHours()` method used in this answer would solve your problem.

Comment: @MallikarjunHampannavar I have made a change to the evaluation logic, please check once it gets peer reviewed.

Comment: I have checked this code with changing device date.. Its not working as per logic.. Every time its showing First time is the same day

Comment: @MallikarjunHampannavar My edit got rejected, here is what I proposed: `if (secondTime > firstTime) {
    alert("First time in the day");
    window.localStorage.setItem('firstTime', secondTime);
  } else {
    alert("Second time in the same day");
  }`

Comment: @camelCaseCoder pls tell weather will it work after changing device date now?? Because i have changed now and its not working.. If i change device date then it show alert like First time in a day right But its showing second time a the same day

Comment: @MallikarjunHampannavar Theoretically it should work. Try debugging as to know what is going wrong.

Comment: @camelCaseCoder Hey it works like charm at first day BUT what about next day, when date and time get chnages..

Comment: What about it? Let's say the user opens the app on the second day, the stored date is of the previous day. So the condition `if (secondTime > firstTime)` will evaluate to `true` so you'll know that it is the first time for that day and you'll store the `secondTime` as `firstTime` in `localStorage`

Comment: @camelCaseCoder check my answer, I have edited your code

Answer (score 1):

This will work like a charm, 
Thanks to @camelcasecoder

```
       var firstTime = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);
        alert("firstTime "+firstTime);
        if (window.localStorage.getItem('firstLaunch') == null){
            window.localStorage.setItem('firstLaunch', firstTime);
            alert("At first time");
        } else {    
            var storedTime = window.localStorage.getItem('firstLaunch');
              // Get a new date, zero it as above and see if its the same time
              // If not, it must be a different day
            var secondTime = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)
            alert("secondTime "+secondTime);
            if (secondTime > storedTime) { 
                alert("First time in the day");
                window.localStorage.setItem('firstLaunch', secondTime); 
            } else { 
                alert("Second time in the same day"); 
            }
         }
```

Comment: Yep, this is exactly what I did to @RobG's answer but my edit got rejected.

Comment: No problem. Upvote @RobG's answer for leading us in the right direction.

Comment: Using `>` or `!=` makes no difference to the logic, clearly if `a > b` is true then `a != b` is also true.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing `new Date().getTime();`, store `new Date().getDate();` and do the comparison. If current date is greater than the stored date, the app is being opened for the first time on that day. So you store this date. And when the next time app is opened, current date won't be greater (it'll be equal) and hence you'll understand that it's not the first time.

**Note:** `getDate()` will only give you the **day** part of the date. For example, for today's date i.e. 10/03/2016, it'll will give you "10". So please include months as well to make your logic foolproof.